# TestNG IR report with screenshot can we send in mail using java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Please some one help me.
TestNG IR report with screenshot  can we send in mail using java selenium ?

for now im able to send only screenshot how can i attach Test NG report in mail.
suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maven send-mail goal** allows you to send a mail during the build, optional you can add attachments too. You can add below goal to you pom.xml. In include tag you have to give relative path of files you have to send.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>send a mail</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>send-mail</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                                <from>builder@myhost.com</from>
                                <subject>a subject</subject>
                                <failonerror>true</failonerror>
                                <mailhost>mail.dummy.ch</mailhost>
                                <mailuser>XXXXX</mailuser>
                                <mailpassword>XXXXX</mailpassword>
                                <htmlMessageFile>src/main/MailContent.html</htmlMessageFile>
                                <receivers>
                                        <receiver>dani</receiver>
                                        <receiver>sam@any-company.com</receiver>
                                </receivers>
                                <fileSets>
                                        <fileSet>
                                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main</directory>
                                                <includes>
                                                        <include>**/*.pdf</include>
                                                </includes>
                                        </fileSet>
                                </fileSets>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```